# I have some (possibly) original results and advisor cannot help, how should I proceed?

Tags: research-process, mathematics

I am a master student in mathematics. I developed a new notion and did calculations for some examples. I believe it is original because I can't find it in literature. Now I want to publish my results, but I don't know if they are publishable or not. I have already asked my advisor but he said he doesn't have the ability to supervise me in that field. Should I just find an expert to talk with? The question is I don't have relations between any experts and me. Because of pandemic, it is also not a good idea to find them personally, so the only remaining idea will be cold email them. But it does not seems a good idea as well, so what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cold emails are very common in this situation, and not at all a bad idea. Indeed, I know of many cold emails that have turned into coauthored papers.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the answer from @user3482749 .

Be careful and professional in the (cold) email. Try to state what you found clearly early on. If you can refer to a paper written by the recipient, do. Many cold emails are of the "I solved the Collatz conjecture" variety and quickly end up in the trash. You don't want yours to be prematurely assigned to that category.

I have tossed many cold emails from cranks. But one led to a joint paper.